# Using php code in symfony YAML as string value

Tags: php, parsing, symfony1, yaml

I want to create some YAML key with value - the code in php. But this code shouldn't be executed - I want to use it as the value itself. How can I do this?

Example:

```
somekey: <?php echo 1; ?>
```

This line shouldn't be recognized as `somekey: 1` after parsing - I want to receive value for `somekey` key as `<?php echo 1; ?>`.

*Update:*

I want to use this to store some code in database (with fixtures.yml) and then load it and use as php-based template.

Comment: Long shot... somekey: <?php echo '<?php echo 1; ?>' ?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I invented my own solution. It looks badly but works:

```
somekey: "<?php echo '<?php echo 1; ?>'; ?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store it as:

```
somekey: [?php echo 1; ?]
```

and replace the [?php ?] with appropriate php tags just before you need to use the template (the layer which loads the yaml could do the work).

Answer (score 1):

i've been using fixtures for migrations purpose and also needed to use php to generate the proper yaml file. My work around this problem was doing something like:

```
<?php $handle=fopen(sfConfig::get('sf_data_dir')."/fixtures/csv/file.csv","r")?>
<?php fgetcsv($handle,0, ";"); ?>
<?php $i=100; ?>
<?php while (($data = fgetcsv($handle,0, ";")) !== false):?>
<?php
$code=trim($data[0]);
$user=trim($data[1]);
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->add(ObjectPeer::CODE, $code);
$unit= objectPeer::doSelectOne($criteria, $error);
if (is_null($unit) || empty($unit))
  continue;
?>
  auto_generated_label_<?php echo 'value'.$i; $i++?>:

    attribute_1: <?php echo $user ?>

    attribute_2: <?php echo $unit->getId() ?>

<?php endwhile ?>
```

So in symfony 1.2 this is working nicely, and remember, always leave a blank like between each yaml entity like in the example, and respect indentation when dealing with php embebbed on a yaml file, because those blank lines will not be there when the yaml parse reads it, so if you not put them, you could end up with somethink like:

auto_generated_label_1: attribute_1: asdasdasd attribute_2: 1233123

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified when (if ever) you want the php code to actually execute. So assuming that you never want it to execute and you're outputting the value to a browser somewhere, try `&lt;?php echo 1; ?&gt;` (or HTML escaping whatever the actual value is)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 1.0:

```
version: <?php echo file_get_contents('1.0/VERSION')."\n" ?>
```

Symfony 1.x:

```
version: "<?php echo file_get_contents('1.1/VERSION') ?>"
```